# Powershell analog to 'quote words'

Tags: powershell

What is the Powershell equivalent to Perl's qw() function? In v2 I can write my own with -split, but I'm assuming that there's an exiting method that I just can't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We include this functionality in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) e.g.:

```
PS> quote-list hello world
hello
world
PS> ql hello world  # using alias
hello
world
```

If you don't want to install PSCX, the function is trivial:

```
Set-Alias ql Quote-List
function Quote-List {$args}
```

Comment: I was hoping for an function in the box, but I'll take this to mean that there isn't one. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, not out of the box but all things considered, it's pretty easy to add to your profile.

Comment: PowerShell Community Extensions has moved to https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `Write-Output` cmdlet (standard alias `write`) works this way because the `-InputObject` param accepts all remaining arguments.

```bsh
PS> write one two three
one
two
three
```